# Adding a linebreak between elements HTML code breaks "parentnode" based javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, nodes

I have [an HTML form with a simple JavaScript function](https://jsfiddle.net/z2gwseuq/) that is meant to send the user to a different link based on the option selected.

```
<form>
<select name="deliveryType">
    <option value="123">Item 1</option>
    <option value="456">Item 2</option>
    <option value="789">Item 3</option>
</select>
<p><a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="javascript:addToCart(this);">Submit</a>
<script>
    function addToCart(t) {
    var dT = t.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1].value;
    alert(dT);
    // location.href = "http://linkprefix.com/?variable=" + dT;
}</script>
</form>
```

It works as expected. The variable `dT` returns the value of the selected option.

However, if there is no line break between `<form>` and `<select>`, `dT` returns `undefined`. But then if I change `childNodes[1]` to `childNodes[0]` it then works again. I don't know why this would happen. I thought `parentNode` and `childNode` were based on HTML elements and the text within them, not line breaks between elements. If I had to guess, the line break is being counted as a text node, but that makes no sense to me. Is that what's happening? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: use `children[0]` - it will work regardless of whitespace - `children` does not include text nodes

Comment: _"the line break is being counted as a text node, but that makes no sense to me"_ - [white-space: pre;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) - When you set this style, it break the lines not only on `<br>` but also by `\n` ( newline characters), so that can be one reason for this to make sencse and keep newlines as Text note inside the `childNodes` array

Comment: @AlonEitan Yes, that makes sense. My confusion was mostly that I assumed that text nodes only existed in elements that can actually contain them validly. I understand now that it was misguided. Using `children` instead of `childNodes` is what I am looking for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As suggested in a comment, changing `childNodes[1]` to `children[0]` makes the function work regardless of any linebreaks or spaces between elements. [See the updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z2gwseuq/1/).

`childNodes` apparently counts all text nodes, while `children` doesn't. Also, linebreaks count as a text node, which makes sense in the strictest interpretation of "text", but wasn't immediately obvious to me.

Answer (score 6):

That's because in HTML, whitespace inside elements is considered as text, and text is considered as nodes (see [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/prop_node_childnodes.asp)). So by adding a line break, you are adding a node, which is why the `<select>` node is accessible through childNodes[1]. If there are no line breaks, then the `<select>` node is accessible through childNodes[0].

Comment: or as `children[0]` regardless of text nodes - of course, usual "internet exploder behaves differently" caveat for IE 8 or less

Comment: @JaromandaX Make sure to note that Netscape Navigator also behaves differently.

Comment: yeah, except nobody uses it, people do still use IE8!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but it is unfortunately not a solution. @Jaromanda offered a fix in his comment, which I've verified and added in an answer.